# Update an array element with inc mongo update

Tags: mongodb, updates, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

HI All I have this Data in mongo,

```
{"articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 1
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

I want to update it using this new data

```
 {"articleId" : [      
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514667",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(6),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

What i need in the output is

```
{"articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 4
            }
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514667",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
    ],

    "count" : NumberLong(7),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
 }
```

Could you please suggest me how can i achieve this this using update operation
My update query will have **tags** field as query parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll never get this in a single query operation as presently there is no way for MongoDB updates to refer to the existing values of fields. The exception of course is operators such as [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/), but this has a bit more going on than can be really handled by this.

You need multiple updates, but there is a consistent model to follow and the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) can at least help with sending all of those updates in a single request:

```js
var updoc = { 
    "articleId" : [      
        {
                "articleId" : "9514666",
                "articleCount" : 3
        },
        {
                "articleId" : "9514667",
                "articleCount" : 3
        }
    ],
    "count" : NumberLong(6),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
};


var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

// Inspect the document variable for update

// For each array entry
updoc.articleId.forEach(function(doc) {
    // First try to match the document and array entry to update
    bulk.find({
        "tags": updoc.tags,
        "articleId.articleId": doc.articleId
    }).update({
        "$inc": { "articleId.$.articleCount": doc.articleCount }
    });

    // Then try to "push" the array entry where it does not exist
    bulk.find({
        "tags": updoc.tags,
        "articleId.articleId": { "$ne": doc.articleId }
    }).update({
        "$push": { "articleId": doc }
    });
})

// Finally increment the overall count
bulk.find({ "tags": updoc.tags }).update({
    "$inc": { "count": updoc.count }
});

bulk.execute();
```

Now that is not "truly" atomic and there is a very small chance that the modified document could be read without all of the modifications in place. And the Bulk API sends these over to the server to process all at once, then that is a lot better than individual operations between the client and server where the chance of the document being read in a non-consistent state would be much higher.

So for each array member in the document to "merge" you want to both try to [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) where the 
member is matched in the query and to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) a new member where it was not. Finally you just want to [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) again for the total count on the merged document with the existing one.

For this sample that is a total of 5 update operations but all sent in one package. Note that the response though will confirm that only 3 operations where applied here as 2 of the operations would not actually match a document due to the conditions specified:

```js
BulkWriteResult({
    "writeErrors" : [ ],
    "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nMatched" : 3,
    "nModified" : 3,
    "nRemoved" : 0,
    "upserted" : [ ]
})
```

So that is one way to handle it. Another may be to just submit each document individually and then periodically "merge" the data into grouped documents using the aggregation framework. It depends on how "real time" you want to do this. The above is as close to "real time" updates as you can generally get.

---

### Delayed Processing

As mentioned, there is another approach to this where you can consider a "delayed" processing of this "merging" where you do not need the data to be updated in real time. The approach considers the use of the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to perform the "merge", and you could even use the aggregation as the general query for the data, but you probably want to accumulate in a collection instead.

The basic premise of the aggregation is that you store each "change" document as a separate document in the collection, rather than merge in real time. So two documents in the collection would be represented like this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548fe1c78ad2c25d4c952eee"),
    "articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 1
            }
    ],
    "count" : NumberLong(1),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548fe2286032bac607405eb3"),
    "articleId" : [
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514666",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            },
            {
                    "articleId" : "9514667",
                    "articleCount" : 3
            }
    ],
    "count" : NumberLong(6),
    "timeStamp" : NumberLong("1416634200000"),
    "interval" : 1,
    "tags" : "famous"
}
```

In order to "merge" these results for a given "tags" value, you want an aggregation pipeline like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Unwinds the array members to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$articleId" },

    // Group the elements by "tags" value and "articleId"
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "tags": "$tags",
            "articleId": "$articleId.articleId",
        },
        "articleCount": { "$sum": "$articleId.articleCount" },
        "timeStamp": { "$max": "$timeStamp" },
        "interval": { "$max": "$interval" },
    }},

    // Now group again creating the array of "merged" items
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$tags",
        "articleId": { 
            "$push": { 
                "articleId": "$_id.articleId",
                "articleCount": "$articleCount"
            }
        },
        "count": { "$sum": "$articleCount" },
        "timeStamp": { "$max": "$timeStamp" },
        "interval": { "$max": "$interval" },
    }}
])
```

So using "tags" and "articleId" ( the inner value ) you group the results together, taking the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of the "articleCount" fields where both of those fields are the same and the [**`$max`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) value for the rest of the fields, which makes sense.

In a second [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pass you then just break the result documents down to "tags", pushing each matching "articleId" value under that into an array. To avoid any duplication the document "count" is summed at this stage and the other values are just taken from the same groupings.

The result is the same "merged" document, which you could either use the above aggregation query to simply return your results from such a collection, or use those results to either just create a new collection for the merged documents ( see the [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator for one option ) or use a similar process to the first example to "merge" these "merged" results with an existing "merged" collection.

---

Accumulating data like this is generally a wide topic, even though a common use case for many. There is a reference project maintained but MongoDB solutions architecture called [HVDF](https://github.com/10gen-labs/hvdf) or High Volume Data Feed. It is aimed at providing a framework or at least a reference example of handling volume feeds ( for which change document accumulation is a case ) and aggregating these in a series manner for analysis.

The actual approaches depend on the overall needs of your application. Concepts such as these are employed internally by a framework like HVDF, it's just a matter of how much complexity you need and the approach that suits your application best for how you need to access the data.

Comment: do we have some java api to call this bulk insert also could you please explain more in detail about the second approach about aggregation

Comment: @viren Your question was not tagged with a specific language or any attempts at code so I answered in the generic sense. All language drivers share the same methods and usage concepts. I've added more material on an approach using aggregation in post processing or querying as well as general information on the subject and some options you might want to employ. If you have problems with the language implementation then you can always post another question which I am sure someone will help you with.

Comment: thanks for teh valuable suggestion I will try the first one as in my use case aggregation does not fit. I will post my query if any is there for your after working on first solution Thank again

Comment: i have one more question your query required an index on artcileId array. Cant we do it without using the index as i already have index on tags field and in my read i do not need to query on articleId. also if index is need will it be on articleId.articleId or onl;y the articleId field

Comment: @viren Just because it is specified in the query clause does not mean it requires an index on the field. It is however a good idea to do so. Note that the updates use a positional operator when setting the value and also look where the element does not exist. The point is either to match the element and update the correct one or to ensure it is not there when choosing to add an element. None of this requires an index, but it generally does make it faster with one in place.

Comment: I am taking about this operation                   bulk.find({
        "tags": updoc.tags,
        "articleId.articleId": { "$ne": doc.articleId }
    }).update({
        "$push": { "articleId": doc }
    }); This find query will use two index i think tags and article array (if  make index like tags:1 and articleId:1) it is a match query what i suppose so how could it work with index dnt take me wrong but every find query needs an index on search field

Comment: @viren No query **needs** an index. For example in testing on your sample I create no indexes. You appear to be confusing the query arguments with a need to index. Also MongoDB only ever uses one index unless in specific cases. If you want an index over multiple fields then you can use a compound index. You should read more on the subject. But your question and the responses have nothing specifically to do with indexes.

Comment: sorry may be i quoted here wrong actually i track almost 20 million records in my db in various collections and this particular update query runs for 300 k records. that is why we use indexes in our db to make this operation faster n safer i think few days back we accidentally run an aggregation over some 1 million records in which match query was not having field on index and it created a complete lock on my db halting all write operations mean time but after using index  for same match query aggregation run only in millisecond and lock was not an issue taht time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67092/discussion-between-viren-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: @viren As I have stated several times, your question has nothing to do with indexes. If you require further understanding of indexes then post another question, as here is not the place. The most efficient index to create here is `db.collection.ensureIndex({ "tags": 1, "articleId.articleId": 1 })` which allows a compound index to be chosen.